# How do I use Doxygen to treat my C code as if it's object oriented?

Tags: c, oop, doxygen

I code almost all my C as if it's object oriented.  What I mean is that even though object orientation isn't built into C, I structure my data, methods and structs as if they are objects with inheritance, member functions, constructors and properties.  Here's an example:

```
// a class with some properties who's superclass is t_Module
typedef struct StutterModule{
    t_Module BASE;
    bool aBooleanProperty;
}t_StutterModule;
// a constructor that mallocs my struct
t_StutterModule* StutterModule_New(void);  
// a destructor for my class
void Stutter_Kill(t_Module *m); 
// a method
long Stutter_Perform(struct Module* m, long myParam);
```

What is the best way to get doxygen to treat the typedef as if it's a class that inherits from t_Module, has one extra property, and has three methods, one of which is a constructor?

**That is, how do I get it to look like oop-style documentation?**

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean with "oop-style" i.e. how should it look like and how does it look like when you use a "real" oop solution. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem.

Comment: I think it involves the `\memberof`, `\implements`, `\extends`, `\public`, `\protected` and `\private` Doxygen commands. Doxygen ships with an example, "manual.c", that uses some of those.

Comment: @albert I believe I have edited the question to further clarify what I mean by a "real" oop solution.   The whole point is that C isn't, out of the box object oriented like java.  It doesn't include syntax for defining classes as such.  The programmer must imagine the object orientation.  I'm asking how I can get doxygen to "imagine" my code as object oriented as well.

Comment: You just placed some normal C comments, nothing doxygen can do something with. Just try the C solution and show us what you are missing. See also the suggestions fro @IanAbbott

Comment: I got confused by the rest of the comments.What you actually want is your Doxygen Documentation look like the ones in OOP (Java,C++ etc) ??Is that right?

Comment: Here is a link to the Doxygen "manual.c" example I mentioned: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/examples/manual.c or https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doxygen/doxygen/master/examples/manual.c (raw)

Comment: @IanAbbot This is exactly what I needed.  The only thing is that it seems to treat the struct and the typedef as separate datastructures no matter what.  Although, from some further research it looks as if typedef struct a {}t_A; is a very common mistake?!

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Yeah, this is about it.  and it seems almost solved from manual.c which I did not get since I downloaded doxygen as an application for mac.

Comment: Oh cool.Keep in mind that you can always generate a Doxygen xml using doxygen -l layout.xml and edit the output xlm.

Comment: @Audiomatt You might need to set `TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT = YES` in the config file.

Comment: @IanAbbot THAT WAS IT!  Wow thank you so so much!!